# Are fulfilling and rewarding interchangeable in this context?

Tags: difference

A: I'm sorry I couldn't make your job seem just a little but fulfilling/rewarding.

Can "fulfilling" and "rewarding" be used interchangeably here?

Comment: Yes they can, although rewarding implies material gain and fulfilling implies satisfaction.

Comment: The *words* can be interchanged, but switching them will alter the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @user118626 I think you meant "more" in place of "but" in your question. Or, mabye "bit".

Answer (score 0):

Both "fulfilling" and "rewarding" are often applied to "jobs" and so they both may be used. They mean slightly different things, because rewarding *could* imply material gain.

fulfilling: providing happiness or satisfaction. emotionally or artistically satisfying.
rewarding: Giving or resulting in reward or satisfaction.

"little but" should be "little more" or "little bit more".

On a side note, the original sentence seems a little bit unusual to me, because the person to make the determination of whether or not a job is fulfilling is the person doing the job. A job does not seem to be fulfilling based on someone else's description. It "is" or "is not" fulfilling, based on the actual experience of doing the work.  However, it's unclear if the sentence needs to be modified since surrounding context was not provided.